# CrystalReports versão 13.0.2000 não exporta

Tags: .net, webforms, crystal-reports

Estou com um projeto webforms .NET 4.5, com relatórios utilizando o Crystal Reports versão **13.0.2000**. Os relatórios não exportam, não explodem *exceptions*, nada, simplesmente a tela faz um *refresh* de *postback* e nada acontece.

Comment: Você está usando o componente padrão para mostrar o relatório ou está criando uma rotina de exportação?

Comment: Componente padrão, o botão de exportação do próprio CrystalReportViewer

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, segue abaixo a resolução.

```
<cr:CrystalReportViewer 
    ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" 
    OnDataBinding="CrystalReportViewer1_DataBinding" ToolPanelView="None" 
    HasCrystalLogo="False" HasDrilldownTabs="False"   
    HasDrillUpButton="False" HasPrintButton="False" HasSearchButton="False" 
    HasToggleGroupTreeButton="false" HasZoomFactorList="False" 
/>
```

E no arquivo aspx.cs:

```
protected void CrystalReportViewer1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ValidaParametros() && IsPostBack)
        CarregaRelatorio();
}

protected void btnBusca_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
}

private void CarregaRelatorio()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        ds = BuscaDadosRelatorio();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            ValidationError.Display(btnBusca, "Não há registros para o critério de busca informado.", ValidationType.Exclamation);

        ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
        switch (ddlExibicao.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "1":
                report.FileName = "RelLancamentoEstorno.rpt";
                break;
            case "2":
                report.FileName = "RelLancamentoInadimplente.rpt";
                break;
            default:
                report.FileName = "RelLancamento.rpt";
                break;
        }
        string reportLoadPath = BuscaParametro();
        report.Load(Path.Combine(reportLoadPath, Path.GetFileName(report.FileName)));
        report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
    }
    catch
    {
        ValidationError.Display(btnBusca, "Falha ao carregar os dados do relatório.", ValidationType.Sucess);
    }
}
```

O que aconteceu foi o seguinte, o método "CarregaRelatorio" inicialmente era chamado no evento click do botão buscar, mas não funcionava. Então criei o evento "OnDataBinding" no componente do Crystal e no evento click do botão buscar mando executar o "CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind" que por sua vez dispara o evento "OnDataBinding", que faz a chamada para o método "CarregaRelatorio". Com o fluxo exatamente assim (tentei muitas outras coisas, utilizando de várias formas o life cycle da página) consegui fazer com que os milhares de bugs fossem automaticamente resolvidos, paginação, exportação, impressão, erros de js, enfim, essa foi a solução que encontrei espero que ajude.